# issue with append() method in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Option1:

```
  <div class="box">I'm a big box</div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('</div>').append("<div class='newbox'>I'm new box by prepend</div>");
    </script>
```

Option2:

```
<div class="box">I'm a big box</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$('.box').append("<div class='newbox'>I'm new box by prepend</div>");
</script>
```

Question:

Why option1 does not work, option2 work?

Comment: Because </div> is not proper selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass to jQuery a string starting with `"<"` and ending in `">"`, jQuery interprets it as HTML and tries to create a DOM fragment. This fragment isn't added to the DOM, so you're just appending to nowhere.

You probably wanted to select the div that was already in the page :

```
 $('div').append("<div class='newbox'>I'm new box by prepend</div>");
```

Answer (score 2):

The selector in the first option is wrong.  When using a tag selector there is no need to include the open `<` and closing braces `>`, just use the name of the tag in a String literal.

```
<div class="box">I'm a big box</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $('div').append("<div class='newbox'>I'm new box by prepend</div>");
</script>
```

The second option works because you are using a correct class selector, `.box`.

You could combine these two approaches if needed.

```
 $('div.box').append("<div class='newbox'>I'm new box by prepend</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with

```
$('div').append("<div class='newbox'>I'm new box by prepend</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the selector from `$('</div>')` to `$('<div>')`

```
<div class="box">I'm a big box</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$('<div>').append("<div class='newbox'>I'm new box by prepend</div>");
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry but this is wrong. `$('<div>')` creates an entirely new div element which you'd then have to add to the page somehow (e.g. by using appendTo(). If you want to select all the divs already on the page use `$('div')` like other answers have said.